# Eclipse, moving a package from a project to another

Tags: java, eclipse

How can i move an entire package ( along with all its content ) from an existing project to another project inside the same working set? I have tried to right click on the target package, which is contained in the first project, then "move", then i have selected the "src" folder of the second project.
It didn't work, it just created a new empty package inside the second project.
Any ideas?

Comment: change the package presentation so that you see the all packages as a list, not as a tree, down to the level you want to move, then just _drag and drop_

Comment: Why the -1? It looks like a missing feature of hierarchial view.

Comment: no "work around", that's what I do every day...

Comment: the downvote might be because it's describe in eclipse online help, at least the alternative "move" refactoring.

Comment: Sure, but i don't see a reason for which it doesn't work with hierarchial. If i drag and drop something i expect it to be moved, not to find a new empty element and nothing moved. Sounds nonsense/buggy

Comment: in  hierarchical view eclipse does not know if you want to move  the subpackage only or the complete folder structure up to the project root.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change the package presentation so that you see the all packages as a list, not as a tree, down to the level you want to move, then just drag and drop

alternatively select the package to move,
right click -> refactoring -> move
select the project and the source folder in that to move to.

Comment: Thanks, but the second solution is the same i've tried and it just creates a new empty package inside the second project.

Comment: looks like the same problem with the hierarchical package presentation...

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have two different projects and they both load the same libraries:

1. In your new project, right click the folder you want your new package – make a new package.
2. Copy the contents you want from the old project.

That is, if you don't want to use the built-in refractor as suggested.